# How can I stop Windows from blocking an unverified publisher's download?

Tags: windows-xp, download

How do I by-pass Windows blocking my download?

OS is Windows XP SP3

Comment: Are you downloading the file or are you executing a downloaded file? In the first case, what browser do you use? Short inaccurate answer: For the first case, the settings to change this behaviour can be found in Internet Explorer. For the second case, you can go to the properties of the file and click unblock in the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I'm trying to download a .cab file for my printer from the manufacturer's website. I am using IE as that is the browser that the manufacturer supports.

I get no choice to save, it just blocks it and tells me. I cannot see how to find the file properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the site to IE trusted sites. Tools -> Internet Options -> Security -> Sites and add the site. If this doesn't work, try lowering the level of security for trusted sites.

Alternatively, use another browser. Firefox and Chrome won't give you this problem.